# What is my DCOS master hostname?

Tags: nginx, mesos, hostname, dcos

In the nginx tutorial for DC/OS:

https://dcos.io/docs/1.7/usage/tutorials/nginx/

There is repeated reference to this URL:

> http://YOUR-DCOS-MASTER-HOSTNAME/service/nginx

However, I cannot find any mention of what my dcos master hostname is anywhere in the documentation.

I can access the nginx service via going onto m1.dcos/mesos, finding the IP address of the service, and typing that into the browser.

However, I feel like that is not the point of the tutorial and that there is some missing information in the documentation as to what YOUR-DCOS-MASTER-HOSTNAME actually refers to.

How do I find out what my DCOS-MASTER-HOSTNAME is?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It’s the Hostname or IP address of the node on which you installed the master on. Simple as that.

Also, please be aware that you are referring to very outdated docs. The current release is 1.10, and not 1.7